# TSL/SSL error when using the kvk service endpoint

Tags: security, ssl, frontend, postman, devops

I'm moving from using the KVK API from development to production. In the development version I had no problems with the API. When using the only needed endpoint in the production version, I receive the error: (failed)net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE (due to TSL/SSL error).

The api key is correct, there is no error in the url. If I try to use this endpoint using Postman, it will only work if I uncheck the following options in the request settings: Enable SSL certificate verification. Kvk service informs in its documentation that their TSL certificates are needed to use the production version (https://developers.kvk.nl/documentation/install-tls-certificate). I downloaded the certificates and installed it on my machine. An application running locally on my machine still cannot use these endpoints. Can you please guide me on what I should do?
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: It's TLS, not TSL.